# Correct action for this answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471784/two-frustrating-issues-with-onenote/28638709#28638709) which showed up in the first-post queue.  The question asked about some problems encountered while using OneNote (now on-hold as off-topic).  A picture of the answer below:

[image: Answer picture]

This answer perplexed me because it was (supposedly) from someone in Microsoft support.  I thought about a spam flag, but decided that it was not quite spam.  I settled for not-an-answer, which was declined.  What surprises me is the other comment that appears to be from a different, helpful not-an-answer flag.  Can anyone explain the other comment? What would be the most appropriate action for this strange answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the post did ask clarifying questions, and did include a lot of information not involved in actually answering the question (i.e. informing the user of a more appropriate place to ask the question as it is off topic where it was asked) it did also actually answer the question as well, so it's not Not An Answer.

You could add a comment that the clarifying questions don't belong in an answer, and even consider editing them out, but the post does in fact provide an answer.

Comment: Sure that makes sense.  What can explain the other comment that looks auto-generated?

Comment: enumerating the possibilities and answering them seems like a pretty quality answer, for what is likely a vague question.. but that recommendation and comparison to SO Q&A... hmm

Comment: @ryanyuyu Someone else erroneously indicated that this wasn't an answer.

Comment: @Servy Ah.  Ok so their flag should also have been declined like mine?

Comment: @ryanyuyu They didn't flag the post.  They reviewed it, erroneously.

Comment: @Servy Ok those comments are auto-generated from a different review queue action?

Comment: just wanted to clarify my above comment a bit: it's a quality answer for the first, **off-topic** question statement within the OP's question.. However, the second question statement could be considered a problem statement (if OP relates an attempt); the provided answer, in this regards, is low quality. "**Not possible**" (**seems to me**) like it should have been **unsupported**. But that would make the context of that answer **off-topic**, as it's elating only platform/technology support.